# nusb3xhc.sys high CPU usage

Tags: windows-7, usb, cpu-usage, sony-vaio, high-cpu-usage

Lately, I've been observing that my CPU often have higher load than it should.

After digging, I found a very weird and specific problem.

The facts :

- I have a Vaio Z21 (VPCZ21C5E - Core i7 - Win7 x64), the Vaio Power Media Dock, and Plantronics Audio 655 DSP headset
- The problem only occurs when I use the dock, and the headset plugged into the dock
- The problem only occurs if the headset it set as Windows default audio device
- The problem only occurs when specific applications / usages (see below)
- It is the "System" process that takes approximately 20-25% usage. When looking a threads list, I can see that the culprit is a "nusb3xhc.sys" thread.
- I updated my Renesas USB 3 driver to last version (2.1.28). Rebooted of course.

What happens :

- When I load a webpage into a browser, System process goes up to 20-25% for 2 to 15 seconds, and then back to 0.
- But for some specific sites (for example "https://web.whatsapp.com"), the "System" CPU load stays at    20-25%, constantly. As soon as I close the tab, CPU usage comes back to normal (approx 1% for "System" process).
- Of course I tried multiple browsers and remove all browser extensions.
- If I play a music (MusicBee) or a video (VLC), "System" process loads again to 20-25% (~1% if headset unplugged or not default)

I can't find any trace of this problem on Google.

I don't really know where to look now ...

Comment: It sounds like the problem is the dock.  If you plug the headset directly to the computer and set it as the default audio device does this problem happen?

Comment: Yes. As I said, if I unplug the dock, no problem. It's a dock+headset problem. I still don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Verify if its just the sock you have.

Comment: nusb3xhc.sys = NEC Electronics USB 3.0 Host Controller Driver. Try to update the driver.

Comment: NEC USB 3 host controller is the same as Renesas USB 3 host controller, which I updated to last version I found (2.1.28).

Comment: I will try with another dock.

Comment: try 2.1.39: http://www.station-drivers.com/index.php/downloads/Drivers/Renesas-Nec/USB-3.0/Renesas-Nec-uPD720200-720200a-USB3-Controller-Drivers-Version-2.1.39.0-WHQL/

Comment: does the newer driver fixes it?

Comment: Hello magicandre1981. Sorry for my late response, I've been busy these days. I've just installed 2.1.39, and the problem is gone ! Thank you for your link, this version was not listed on official Sony drivers list. Would you copy/paste as an answer so that I can accept it and close the question ?

Comment: ok, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nusb3xhc.sys` is the `NEC Electronics USB 3.0 Host Controller Driver`. Drivers from OEM home pages are often very old. Try the [latest version (Version 2.1.39) that I can find](http://www.station-drivers.com/index.php/downloads/Drivers/Renesas-Nec/USB-3.0/Renesas-Nec-uPD720200-720200a-USB3-Controller-Drivers-Version-2.1.39.0-WHQL/).

Comment: I've just installed 2.1.39, and the problem is gone ! Thank you for your link, this version was not listed on official Sony drivers list.